# Smash product of two different co-$H$ spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider two co-$H$ spaces $X$ and $Y$, equipped with co-multiplications $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$. Both $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ each induce a co-$H$ structure on the smash product $X \wedge Y$:

$$\mu_X \wedge Id_Y \colon X \wedge Y \longrightarrow (X \vee X) \wedge Y \cong (X \wedge Y) \vee (X \wedge Y)$$
$$Id_X \wedge \mu_Y \colon X \wedge Y \longrightarrow X \wedge (Y \vee Y) \cong (X \wedge Y) \vee (X \wedge Y)$$

A-priori, I don't see why these induced co-$H$ structures should be homotopic, but in simple examples they seem to coincide. Is there any reason they should be the same in particular in the case when the spaces involved are not suspensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument). It's a generalization of the observation that the double loop space is homotopy commutative: $X$ and $Y$ define two $H$-space structures on $[X \wedge Y, Z]$ which interchange with each other so the Eckmann-Hilton argument implies that they 1) are homotopic and 2) are homotopy commutative and associative.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea this would be such a general result. How pleasing. Thank you!

Comment: Two group structures on $[ X \wedge Y,Z]$.

Comment: @Paul: well, that depends on whether your convention is that $[X, Y]$ refers to the mapping space or $\pi_0$ of the mapping space. I'm using the first convention here.